# How to retrieve already existing images in Firebase Storage and show it in UICollectionViewCells in Swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

I am trying to retrieve images from Firebase Storage that are uploaded manually(drag and drop) and now I want to show those images in UICollectionViewCells. There are many answers to this question but they use their uploaded path to retrieve the images but how do I get permission and the URL of Firebase Storage of mine? Here is the image of my structure in Firebase Storage and creation of my cells:

[image: this is how i created the folder and inside this there are images that i need to retrieve]

[image: here is the code of simple UICollectionViewCell]

Comment: This is covered in the documentation but the general process is when storing an image in Firebase storage, you would get the download URL at that time and store it in Firestore or the Real Time Database. Then when you want to retrieve the images, the urls are gotten from the database. In your case, if you manually added them to storage, you could get the url from the Firebase console and create a node in one of the databases of where your code could retrieve them from. That being said, there's nothing in the code in your question related to Firebase API so we don't know where you are stuck.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I searched on the internet and i got the same answers as yours. When i store manually images it gives the download url of each image when you click once on image. But i am stuck in how to retrieve that images and stoe it in images array so that i can use in my cells

Comment: Are you asking how to download an image from Storage if you know the url? Can you update your question with the code you've attempted? The Firebase Getting Started guide is pretty good and shows specifically how to accomplish that task [Download Files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files). Have you gone through that?